# Get and change a key value inside an object inside the state react js

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have an object inside my state and I want to be able to grab it and change it, I'm trying to use spread syntax but it's not working:

```
 handleChange = (e) => {
  this.setState({
    
   ...this.state, postData: [this.state.postData.email, e.target.value]
    
  })
 
  }
```

this is how I'm trying but apparently something its wrong

Comment: Is `postData` an array already existing in the state? Also: please consider using `this.setState(prev => { return {...prev, [someKey]: 'someValueToOverridePrev'}});` to rather than `...this.state` - if it is okay to do so.

Comment: this is state: const initialState = {
   initialMSG: '',
   initialPos: grid[4],
   initialMove: 0,
   initialCoord: coordinates[4],
   postData:{
    'x': 2,
    'y': 2,
    'steps': 0,
    'email': ''
  }
}

Comment: Okay, so `postData` is not an array. It is an object. So, please try: `this.setState(prev => ({ ...prev, postData: {...prev.postData, email: e.target.value}}));` if the `handleChange` event corresponds to `email`. If the event's target is not email, then please share what it is.

Comment: yes, its email, let me try, thanks...

Comment: that did work, thank you so much, also I have another question if you could help me...how do I change 2 values at the same time? lest say I want to change steps.

Comment: `this.setState` is not a react hook.

Comment: Have posted an answer with an assumption that is what you need. If you simply need to update two values and both of those are available with you (say in variables `stepsValue`, `emailValue`), then please try: `this.setState(prev => ({ ...prev, postData: { ...prev.postData, steps: stepsValue, email: emailValue}}));`. It is my observation that more often than not, the `handleChange` gets invoked each time an input changes - so, chances are low that multiple values will be concurrently changing.

Answer (score 0):

Assumed objective:

To use `handleChange` method and update different props within a nested state object.

Example: update `steps` and `email` in the below state object:

```
this.state = {
  initialMSG: '',
  initialPos: 0,
  initialMove: 0,
  initialCoord: 0,
  postData: { 'x': 2, 'y': 2, 'steps': 0, 'email': '' }
};
```

**Code Snippet**

This below code snippet may provide one possible solution to achieve the assumed/desired objective:

```js
class Thingy extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      initialMSG: '',
      initialPos: 0,
      initialMove: 0,
      initialCoord: 0,
      postData: { 'x': 2, 'y': 2, 'steps': 0, 'email': '' }
    };
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
  };
  
  handleChange = e => {
    const obj = {[e.target.name]: e.target.value};
    console.log('updating postData: ', obj);
    this.setState(
      prev => ({
        ...prev,
        postData: {
          ...prev.postData,
          ...obj
        }
      })
    );
  };
  
  render() {
    const { steps, email } = this.state.postData;
    return (
      <div>
        Steps:
        <input value={steps} onChange={this.handleChange} name='steps' />
        <br/>
        Email:
        <input value={email} onChange={this.handleChange} name='email' />
      </div>
    );
  }
};

ReactDOM.render(
  <div>
    DEMO
    <Thingy />
  </div>,
  document.getElementById('reactDiv')
);
```

```html
<div id='reactDiv' />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

**Explanation**

- The `handleChange` method accepts the event `e` as the parameter
- The two `<input />` elements for `steps` and `email` both have `name`
- When the values change, the same `handleChange` is triggered
- However, for `steps` the `name` (ie, the `e.target.name`) will be `steps` and for `email` it will be `email`
- This distinction is used to update the relevant prop within `postData`